# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu May 24 2018 14:00:00 GMT+0200"

Tags: datetime, jodatime, simpledateformat, date-format

I´m trying to convert a String date like "Thu May 24 2018 14:00:00 GMT+0200" to Joda DateTime (v.2.9.9) but I obtain Invalid format exception:

```
    String pattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);

    for (int i=0; i < arrayHorarios.length; i++) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(arrayHorarios[i]);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? My goal is to convert all Strings containing dates to Java Dates and then save them into DB... what´s the easiest way to do it? (with or without Joda).

**EDIT:**

I changed to the correct pattern. Using Java DateFormat was useless too:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String[] arrayHorarios = mapper.readValue(horariosSave, String[].class);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    //sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    List<Date> hor = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date date = new Date();

    try {

        for (int i=0; i < arrayHorarios.length; i++) {
            // conversión de String a Date de los valores                
            System.out.println("Horario nº:"+i);
            System.out.println("String = "+arrayHorarios[i]);

            date = df.parse(arrayHorarios[i]);
            System.out.println("Date = " + df.format(date));          

            hor.add(date);
        }

        System.out.println("Clases guardadas:"+hor.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This way I get this exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri May 25 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0200"
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Comment: Could it be a locale issue? “Thu” and “May” are in English, so if your formatter is using a non-English locale, it won’t work.

Comment: I added withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH) but that didn´t work too. It´s a parsing issue relating to GMT+0200 because without that characters everything works fine, but I need to save that too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your Joda-Time formatter parses your string nicely into 2018-05-24T14:00:00.000+02:00 on my computer.

Comment: Joda is working fine in my computer if I add 'GMT'z to pattern and withOffsetParsed() method to formatter. Anyway saving Joda DateTime in Hibernate is more complex than Java LocalDateTime. I wonder if there is a way to do it with Java 8 Util Time.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

> I wonder if there is a way to do it with Java 8 Util Time.

Of course there is.

```
    String pattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String horario = "Thu May 24 2018 14:00:00 GMT+0200";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(horario, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Prints:

> 2018-05-24T14:00+02:00

Imports used are:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
```

### Joda-Time

Not that you’ll regret upgrading to `java.time`, your Joda-Time code seems to be working too:

```
    String pattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
    String horario = "Thu May 24 2018 14:00:00 GMT+0200";
    DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(horario);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints:

> 2018-05-24T14:00:00.000+02:00

I suspect that your problem may be somewhere else.

PS You may already be aware that [the Joda-Time home page](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) says:

> Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).

Answer (score 0):

To convert Java Date to Joda DateTime:-

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
```

With TimeZone, if required:-

```
TimeZone timeZone= dateTime.getZone().toTimeZone();
DateTime dateTimeNew = new DateTime(date.getTime(), timeZone);
Date dateTimeZone = dateTime.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(timeZone).toDate();
```

Comment: From String to Joda DateTime, not from Java Date

Comment: Oh, I see, if so, please check your arry data of value . if It is not match with your pattern, it will show this error.

Comment: String of array are like “Thu May 24 2018 14:00:00 GMT+0200” and my pattern is "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z".